# nodeJS setinterval doesn't exit callback

Tags: node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I'm writing a program with socket.io that includes a setInterval function.
But I keep getting the wrong answers, then I wrote a basic setup with 2 counters one client side and one server side who have to refresh every 500ms but only the client side logs the data in the console. It's like the setInterval keeps the other code from running.

here is the code

server.

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
        console.log("test");

        io.sockets.on('count', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    setInterval(function(){var count=0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            count = count + 1;
            socket.emit('count', count);
        }},500);
});`
```

client

```
<script>
    var socket = io();
    var count=0;

    socket.on('count', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        count = count +1;
        socket.emit('count',count);
    }

    </script>
```

I know I have to clean up my setInterval afterwards but this code is just for testing reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find same solution with some more details in log:-
`server.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('count', function(data){
    // client message will be logged here
    console.log(" client message " + data);
  });

  setInterval(function(){var count=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      count = count + 1;
      socket.emit('count', " server count " + count);
      console.log(" server message " + count); // this i server message sent to client
    }},500);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and `client script`

var socket = io();

```
 // Add a connect listener
  socket.on('connect',function() {
    console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
  });
  // Add a disconnect listener
  socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    console.log('The client has disconnected!');
  });

  var count=0;

  socket.on('count', function(data){
    console.log("server message" +  data); // this is message come from server
  });

  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    count = count +1;
    socket.emit('count',count); // client sends this information to server.
  }
```

Your solution is correct but please note that when client emit message, it will display on node terminal or console and when server emit then it will be visible on browser console.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't see the {console.log("client message" +data);} on my server

Comment: // this is client message at server end

io.sockets.on('count', function (data) {
      
        console.log(data);
    });

Comment: yes but shouldn't this be logging on my nodeJs console?

Comment: Yes it will log to nodeJs console but not browser console. I have written above code to help you understand that client information will be passed to server and that's why I have put console.log("client message "), Please let me know if you want more information on this point.

Comment: I have updated comment after each log, please let me know if you have any problem in this.

Comment: I understand that but when running your code or my example it does not log the data on the server from socket.on('count', fc()...  });
at any given point. that's why i tought the setInterval was keeps the server busy.

Comment: Let me quickly share you my running code to dropbox and will discuss if that is not working at your end

Comment: Please find google drive link for code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yiLSCQVv9TUjVQN1RJODhIVDA

Comment: I have that running also but this doesn't sort the issue.

Comment: so what's issue you are facing